# Preposition after "price"

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

I have heard about:

> What's the price **of** the book.
>
> What's the price **for** the book.

Today I have seen a sentence:

> We aim to bring down prices **on** all our computers.

What are the uses of **"on"** with the word **"price"?**

Explain.

Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, your questions frequently include the one-word sentence, "Explain." You should be aware that this comes across as demanding and impolite: the command "explain" without a softening modifier like "please explain" is more typical for a situation like an angry parent confronting a naughty child.  You should avoid this usage unless you want to convey impatience or anger.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of this as referring to a *price label*. That's not literally what it's doing, but it's a convenient way to think about it.

Each product has a (conceptual) price label saying how much it costs. That is referred to as the price, and because you can think of it as a label on the product, you can use *on*. It has no difference in meaning to *of*.

> "You want the blue one? Let me check the price on that."

**However**, that's not all that's going on when you have the "bring down prices* example. There, you have different ways of phrasing it depending what preposition you use:

> We aim to bring down prices **on** all our computers.
>   We aim to bring down **the** prices **of** all our computers.

Essentially, you can have *bring* as a transitive verb, *prices* as the subject, and *down* as an adverb, in which case *prices* needs a definite article and *of* is acting genitively, and you could say "all our computers' prices" rather than "prices of all our computers". You could use other prepositions that act to form genitives instead of *of*.

Alternatively, you can have *bring down prices* as an intransitive phrasal verb, with *on all our computers* acting as an adverbial. That adverbial can't use as many prepositions as the genitive would, and *on* is the only one you would use naturally.